# Is there a short-hand to call several functions in parallel in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Given I have a function in Java which has to do a lot of work. This work consists of several different things to do, which are defined in their own functions and are independent of each other.

```
void myFunction() {
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

However, these functions run one after the other (just as I coded it), which is not necessary here and makes the whole function run longer than necessary. Running both functions in its own thread requires significantly more code:

```
void myFunction() {
    UncaughtExceptionHandler eh = (th, t) -> { throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t); };
    try {
        Thread foo = new Thread(() -> foo());
        Thread bar = new Thread(() -> bar());
        foo.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(eh);
        bar.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(eh);
        foo.start();
        bar.start();
        foo.join();
        bar.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

So I wonder if there is some built-in approach in newer Java versions to do this more efficiently, something like:

```
Threads.doParallel(
    () -> foo(),
    () -> bar()
);
```

Comment: Yes, but I think that would be needed so often that it could exist. There have been a lot of new APIs since Java ≥8 and I am sometimes surprised what there is. But I have not found anything, so I thought, I ask first.

Comment: Have you checked [CompletableFuture.runAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-)?

Comment: You can check for [ExecutorService](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-wait-for-threads) approach

Comment: `CompletableFuture`'s are the best. Use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest I get, using CompletableFutures is this :

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(new FutureTask<Void>(() -> foo(), null)),
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(new FutureTask<Void>(() -> bar(), null))
).get();
```

This doesn't have the handling for excptions in `foo()` or `bar()`. But we can add that, sacrificing some brevity :

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(new FutureTask<Void>(() -> foo(), null)),
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(new FutureTask<Void>(() -> bar(), null))
)
.exceptionally(t -> {
    throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t);
})
.get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ExecutorService`:

```java
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
final Runnable foo = () -> ...;
final Runnable bar = () -> ...;

executor.submit(foo);
executor.submit(bar);

executor.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using CompletionService which could run tasks concurrently and collect the results as they become ready.

```
    public void doParallel() {
        Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        CompletionService<Boolean> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
        Future future1 = completionService.submit( () -> foo() );
        Future future2 = completionService.submit( () -> bar() );
        try {
            completionService.take();
            completionService.take(); // second task
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            future1.cancel( true );
            future2.cancel( true );
        }
    }
```